# Why can't I edit polygons once they have been saved to MySQL?

Tags: qgis, mysql

I have a simple table with an id field and a polygon field in mySql.
Using QGIS I can add new polygons and give them an id. Before saving them I can also edit them.

But once a polygon has been saved it cannot be edited any more: every time I move it, it simply moves back to the original position when I save the edits. Added points disappear when saving.

The same happens with a point field in a different table.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but you might open your poly table and see if MySQL recognizes the `id` as both Primary Key (PK) and Auto Incrementing (AI). If you don't have PK specified on your intended `id` value, I could forsee that giving you some grief. ..sorry if that's not it. :/

Comment: That was it! It was Primary Key but not Auto Incrementing. I had no idea this was required. Thanks a whole lot, elrobis! How can I mark your answer as the accepted?

Comment: No problem---I'm glad that did the trick. And welcome to the site. I'll just copy/paste the comment into an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), when it imports and creates MySQL tables, does not flag the `OGR_FID` field as Primary Key (PK) and/or Auto Increment (AI)---I forget which it is. But as you found out, it seems QGIS has a similar behavior.

With `ogr2ogr`, I usually experience this as MySQL Workbench complaining that it cannot edit the data, and I fix this by opening the table to ALTER it, and making sure the `OGR_FID` field is flagged for both PK and AI.

It sounds like applying this solution against QGIS/MySQL also did the trick for you. Good deal---I'm happy it was that simple. 8)

Comment: Alex, out of curiosity, did you create the table/layer directly within QGIS, or did you import it using another method?

Comment: I created the tables in on my Webserver on mySql, then added them as vectorlayer.  What I have learned: the table needs a Primary Key and Auto Incrementing. AND: It only works with one (the first) geometry field - more are ignored and when I present them with a view editing does not work.